# Does pip handle extras_requires from setuptools/distribute based sources?

Tags: python, setuptools, pip, distribute

I have package "A" with a setup.py and an [extras_requires](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) line like:

```
extras_require = {
    'ssh':  ['paramiko'],
},
```

And a package "B" that depends on util:

```
install_requires = ['A[ssh]']
```

If I run `python setup.py install` on package B, which uses `setuptools.command.easy_install` under the hood, the `extras_requires` is correctly resolved, and paramiko is installed.

However, if I run `pip /path/to/B` or `pip hxxp://.../b-version.tar.gz`, package A is installed, but paramiko is not.

Because pip "installs from source", I'm not quite sure why this isn't working. It should be invoking the setup.py of B, then resolving & installing dependencies of both B and A.

Is this possible with pip?

Comment: Update your pip `pip install -U pip` and then `pip install ".[test]"` should install named `extra_require` section

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is suppported since pip 1.1, which was released in February 2012 (one year after this question was asked).

Comment: That appears to be it. My grep over the pip source tree didn't turn it up, as I was looking for the string "extras_require", not just "extras".

Comment: For posterity, use `pip install packagename[extra1,extra2]==2.1` as described in example 6 [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#examples) and in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26285009/1959808).

Answer (score 43):

We use `setup.py` and `pip` to manage development dependencies for our packages, though you need a newer version of `pip` (we're using 1.4.1 currently).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup
from myproject import __version__ 

required = [
    'gevent',
    'flask',
    ...
]

extras = {
    'develop': [
        'Fabric',
        'nose',
    ]
}

setup(
    name="my-project",
    version=__version__,
    description="My awsome project.",
    packages=[
        "my_project"
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    scripts=[
        'runmyproject',
    ],
    install_requires=required,
    extras_require=extras,
)
```

To install the package:

```sh
$ pip install -e . # only installs "required"
```

To develop:

```
$ pip install -e .[develop] # installs develop dependencies
```

Comment: It appears that `pip install .[develop]` (without the `-e`) does not work, and you need to use an editable installation if you want to install extras of `.`.

Comment: When using `pip install -e .[develop]`, does pip install gevent and Fabric? And where is this behavior documented?

Comment: That command will install everything, `gevent`, `flask`, `Fabric`, and `nose`. Pip internally uses `setuptools` for their build system https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip/?highlight=setuptools#build-system-interface. `extras_require` is an option in `setuptools` for installing 'extras' https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies

Comment: @JeremyBanks Here is the [PIP issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1236). It has already been fixed in the code base, so it should theoretically be fixed in the newest version.

Comment: Is it possible to install multiple extras_require together? Like combine optional support for 2 different things? `.[option1,option2]`?

Comment: is it possible to ONLY install [develop]?

Answer (score 22):

The answer from @aaronfay is completely correct but it may be nice to point out that if you're using `zsh` that the install command `pip install -e .[dev]` needs to be replaced by `pip install -e ".[dev]"`.

Comment: I thought I am stupid but now I know: ["zsh uses square brackets for globbing / pattern matching."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30539963/1611317)