# setuptools and pip: choice of minimal and complete install

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

We've made a library which depends on other libraries. But there are necessary (e.g. for server batch processing) and optional dependencies (e.g. for clients with GUI).

Is something like this possible:

```
pip install mylib.tar.gz  # automatically downloads and installs with the minimal set of dependencies

pip install mylib.tar.gz  --install-option="complete"  # automatically installs with all dependencies
```

I've found the `extra_require` flag, but how can I tell `pip` to use them? The `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

# ...

# Hard library depencencies:
requires = [
    "numpy>=1.4.1",
    "scipy>=0.7.2",
    "traits>=3.4.0"
]

# Soft library dependencies:
recommended = {
    "mpl": ["matplotlib>=0.99.3"],
    "bn": ["bottleneck>=0.6"]
}

# ...

# Installer parameters:
setup(
    name = "mylib",
    #...
    install_requires = requires,
    extras_require = recommended
)
```

Comment: This is not yet possible but I raised a bug for fixing it at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4340 -- when this will be fixed you will be able to use `pip install foo[all]`

Answer (score 22):

You can install the packages in `extras_require` by appending the name of the recommended dependency in square brackets (i.e. `[mpl]` or `[bn]` in your case) to the package name in pip.

So to install 'mylib' with the additional requirements, you would call pip like this:

```
pip install 'mylib[mpl]'
pip install 'mylib[bn]'
```

This will first download and install the extra dependencies, and then `mylib`'s core dependencies.

This is anologous to how you declare those dependencies with setuptools: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies (see the `install_requires` value in the third example)

Comment: Ah okay! And this works also with more? `pip install 'mylib[mpl,bn]'` or whats the syntax? And it's possible that all libs are installed with something like `pip install 'mylib[complete]'`, when adding `"complete": ["matplotlib>=0.99.3", "bottleneck>=0.6"]` to the `recommended` dict?

Comment: I don't know if it works with multiple extra dependencies, I've only ever used this with single ones... But your second solution should work, best like this: `extras_require = dict(('complete', itertools.chain.from_iterable(recommended)) + recommended)`. This way you don't have to declare those dependencies twice in your `setup.py` but can re-use the values from `recommended`.

Comment: Yes, I think it only works with a package name. You could of course extract the tgz to a temporary folder and install it via `pip install .[extras]`

Answer (score 10):

So pip is actually quite picky about installing libraries with extra requirements

```
pip install -e ".[extra,requirements]"    # works with file paths
pip install "package[extra,requirements]" # works when downloading packages
pip install ".[extra,requirments]"        # DOES NOT WORK
```

I think this is down to how the RequirementsSpec parser works, and pip does some extra magic with the `-e` flag. Anyhow after much head banging, here's a mildly ugly workaround

```
pip install "file:///path/to/your/python_code#egg=SomeName[extra,requirements]"
```

The `egg=SomeName` part is basically ignored, but pip correctly picks up the extra requirements

#### Caveats

- Tested with pip 1.5.6 so make sure you're using a current version of pip.
- As far as I can tell, the `file:///` syntax is undocumented in pip, so I'm not sure if it'll change in the future. It looks a bit like the [VCS Support](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support) syntax but I was a bit surprised it worked.
- You could also get around this by running your own pypi server, but that's a bit out of scope.