# Python: distribute two packages from the same codebase

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

suppose I have this project `xxxx`, I'd like to distribute two packages for it:
`xxxx` and `xxxx-lite`, the difference is that `xxxx` has some extra dependencies for extra features, while `xxxx-lite` does not.

I tried to have one `setup.py` and `setup-lite.py`, but when I run `python setup-lite.py sdist`, the package includes `setup-lite.py` instead of `setup.py`, which makes it uninstallable by `pip`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`extras-require`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=extras_require#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)

Related to [setuptools and pip: choice of minimal and complete install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096155/setuptools-and-pip-choice-of-minimal-and-complete-install)

Comment: thanks! I've read about `extra-require`, but it seems using it gives: `xxxx` and `xxxx[full]`

Comment: instead of `xxxx-lite` and `xxxx`, there is a slight difference

Comment: In that case, you can add `xxxx-lite` to `install_requires` for `xxxx`; just treat them as separate projects with separate `setup.py` files, where `xxxx` depends on `xxxx-lite`.