# How to I change the Manifest.in depending on the extra_requires I wish to use?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

My problem is that a project I'm working with comes shipped with all of the training data needed to reproduce its results. I want the default installation (`pip install package`) to include all this stuff, but a specific installation (`pip install package[train_only]`) to not.

The two ways I want to slim it down are:

1. Having different manifests for the default and the train_only version, where the default manifest is more inclusive, and
2. Having different install_requires for each, where the default is more inclusive.

I know how to install **extra** stuff using `extra_requires`, but how do I install less?

Comment: [extras] syntax is for including extra stuff.  I don't think you can use it to subtract stuff.

Comment: That's unfortunate but makes sense. Is there a way to do conditional manifiests? Also, related: is there a way to access the thing in brackets from inside of setup.py? I could just have different setup functions run for different cases.

Comment: Maybe this question could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096155/setuptools-and-pip-choice-of-minimal-and-complete-install

Answer (score 1):

The `distribution[extras]` syntax is just used for specifying additional *dependencies* for optional features, this typically means collecting other distributions to install.  You can not use this feature to control package data in any way.

Conditional `MANIFEST.in` and/or package data is unsupported in distutils and setuptools.  Your best option would be creating the hooks for a custom post-install script.

If you are willing to consider moving to an "additive" installation model for the extra data instead, you have a nicer option available:

```
pip install mypackage           # to install without extra training data stuff
pip install mypackage[mystuff]  # to install with extra training data stuff
```

Then you will create a separate distribution `mystuff` which will include all of the training data needed.