# How to package a Python module with extras as default?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, packaging, pypi

My Python package has [optional features (`extras_require`)](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) and I would prefer them to be selected by default.

More specifically, I'd like that `pip install mypackage` behaves like `pip install mypackage[extra]` and that I can install a minimal version with something like `pip install mypackage[core]`.

```
setup(
    name="mypackage",
    ...
    extras_require={
        "extra":  ["extra1>=1.2", "extra2"],
        "core": [],
    }
)
```

Is it possible to achieve this with a setup script similar to above?

Comment: Pretty much same question here:  [How to I change the Manifest.in depending on the extra_requires I wish to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48191319/674039)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the current state of Python packaging metadata & tooling.

See [a long discussion here](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1503) as to why.

Comment: Is there any update on this 2 years later? Is it possible with `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: Still not possible, but it was discussed at length at PyCon US 2022: https://speakerdeck.com/uranusjr/lets-fix-extras-in-core-metadata-3-dot-0