# Optional, dynamic dependencies at Python runtime

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm building a complex Python application with a maximalist approach in terms of support for different libraries, some of which are machine learning libraries that use several gigabytes. I am now getting ready to make a release of the project, but I've realized the build size is enormous and 99% of it is not my code, and some of it may never be called by the user.

What I'd like to be able to do is have the user download a release with the minimal dependencies, and if they choose to use other ones in the GUI, prompt them and install them at runtime, and maybe even rebuild the application with `pyinstaller`.

I don't expect all my users to be developers, so just having a configurable build script isn't the best option, and I don't want to ship multiple releases.

Is what I'm describing possible with Python, and is it a common pattern? How would I accomplish something like this?

If this question is better suited to the Software Engineering stack exchange, I can move it there.

EDIT:
Some of my packages are also Linux-only or Windows-only. I want to release my project as a portable executable with something like PyInstaller. I don't expect my users to understand how to manage a `venv` or system Python version either. I suppose I could understand making another piece of software that installs and builds the program by and manages its own Python version, `venv`, and executable like an installed system package. Is such a complicated, overbearing solution necessary to handle this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19096782/7976758 You're looking for optional dependencies using `extras_require` See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+optional+dependencies

Comment: This is a good start, however, I don't want to distribute the project as a module for other developers, I'm trying to distribute a small binary the user can optionally install optional dependencies with at runtime.

Comment: Then `pip` is a wrong tag here. `pip`/`setuptools` cannot do that, You need to write your own installer.

Comment: @phd oh gosh okay that sounds itemidating, I was kind of wondering if there were any established packages / practices for handling this behavior already.

Comment: Not in Python world, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you engage tools like PIP programmatically if necessary?

Comment: If you don't intent to distribute the python source, pyInstaller is anyhow just a poor-man's protection, but if you don't mind distributing the source, the approach might be to just zip the python environment as your package and make your own installer that adds a script to start the main program to the path. Then, pip is included, and you can programmatically invoke it to install (even uninstall) the additional packages.
You won't get around making one package per operative system.

Comment: What about building in installer for your library? e.g. https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist - this uses the NSIS installer

Comment: Hey @TessaPainter, are you talking about the https://github.com/FlorianEagox/weeablind project? because I cannot find the `setup.cfg` or the `setup.py` files. I would love to contribute to the project if it is open source and fix the above-described issue for you.

Comment: Haiya @ArtyomVancyan. Yep that's correct, I dont have any setup or anything, right now I just run the setup. You're welcome to contribute if you have ideas on how to solve this problme, that'd be rad!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with Python what what you're describing, and it's actually a common pattern in software development, known as `lazy loading` or `dynamic dependencies`. It allows you to defer the installation and loading of certain dependencies until they are actually needed by the user.

- you can use Python's built-in `importlib` module, which provides functions for programmatically importing modules at `runtime`.
- Identify the optional dependencies that you want to include in your application but not ship by default. libraries that are not essential for the core functionality of your application.
- Modify your code to use dynamic imports for these optional dependencies like:

```py
import importlib

def use_optional_library():
    try:
        optional_lib = importlib.import_module('optional_lib')
        # Use the optional library here
    except ImportError:
        # Handle the case when the library is not available
        pass
```

- In your GUI, provide a way for the user to `enable` or `disable` the usage of these optional libraries. When the user chooses to enable a specific library, you can call the corresponding function that uses `importlib.import_module()` to load the library `dynamically`.
- To handle the installation of the optional dependencies, you can use a package manager like `pip` or `conda` or library like `pipenv` or `poetry`.
- You can use the `subprocess` module to execute the package manager commands programmatically.
- distribute your application as a portable executable using `PyInstaller`, you can include the `optional` libraries as data files rather than as direct dependencies. This way, they won't be bundled with the executable by `default`, but you can load them dynamically at runtime if the user chooses to enable them.

This `approach` adds some complexity to your codebase, it allows you to provide a more `flexible` and `customizable` experience for your users without bloating the initial download size.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the machine learning models can be used for inference without installing complete ml framework they are built on. There is no general way of minimizing or shrinking the distribution to include only useful modules (not possible to know all possible flows on runtime and files your model will use and include only those in dict). you can try creating a minimalistic runtime just to do inference using your model and other application logic. For example try using mlflow-skinny or onyx runtime and see if you can reduce dist size. if nothing works you may need to dig deeper and implement some module to do inference yourself to avoid fat dist.

Answer (score -1):

Installing dependencies on the fly is a multistep task, that heavily depends on how you plan to run your app on the client side. While I don't know any well known library that solves this task in general, you can implement your own solution.

1. If your distribution depends on being installed with `pip` the easiest solution is to use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to call `pip` from within your app and download the dependency.
2. If your distribution uses something like PyInstaller, then it is already bundled with a python interpreter though often without the `pip` package. A solution could be to download the dependency using [`urllib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3) and make it available to that interpreter, e.g. either by appending the downloaded folder location to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) or by placing the folder in a specific location as described by your bundler.

Comment: Downvoting because Python's setuptool already has a built-in `extras_require` that allows one to `pip install package[extra]`. Having a library download external dependencies via the way suggested above sounds like a massive security concern, generally not maintainable, and worst of all, a breach of trust with the end-user.

Comment: @felipe OP said, she does not expect all her users to be terminal affine. Additionally bundlers don't include pip in the bundle, so if there is no python on the client side, one would have to download pip first, which yields the same problem.

Comment: @felipe How would this be a security risk? My application is fully open source, I'd just like to be able to distribute small binaries for accessibility reasons, and I suppose control the venv packages programmatically from the GUI. The  only downside I've noticed right away is that PyInstaller's build of my project is much smaller (but still a couple gigs) compared to the venv (~8GB) and if users could download and rebuild the binary, that might be optimal.

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is a design pattern called builder. The principale is to create a default builder, modify the builder to add the librairy you want and finaly create your object with all the librairies given in parameters.

Here are some links about this design pattern:

- https://python.plainenglish.io/design-patterns-in-python-builder-pattern-d921fbac7fb3
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/builder-design-pattern-in-java