# should pytest et al. go in tests_require[] or extras_require{testing[]}?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am writing a python program which uses py.test for testing and now one test also depends on numpy. Where in my setup.py should I add those dependencies?

Currently the relevant part of my setup.py looks something like this:

```
[...]
'version': '0.0.1',
'install_requires': [],
'tests_require': ['pytest'],
'cmdclass': {'test': PyTest},
'extras_require': {
    'testing': ['pytest'],
},
[...]
```

Having `pytest` twice feels already somewhat strange and I'm not sure where to add numpy.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### According to the docs

**[tests_require](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html)** are additional packages that are obtained when using [*setuptools*'s *test*](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite) command. They are not installed on the system.

**[extras_require](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies)** are optional additional packages grouped by the feature name. The list of packages are installed to use that feature and there are various ways to install them. See [Does pip handle extras_requires from setuptools/distribute based sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796936/does-pip-handle-extras-requires-from-setuptools-distribute-based-sources)

### My interpretation

**tests_require** should be packages that are used in the tests such as [*numpy*](http://www.numpy.org/) and not packages that are used to conduct testing like [*pytest*](https://pytest.org/latest/contents.html) or [*nose*](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). **tests_require** would need to be moved or copied to a "testing" feature in **extras_require** when testing outside of *setuptools*.

Use **extras_require** to make a testing package such as *pytest* optional. Use **setup_requires** to require it.

*pytest* and *nose* can be integrated with *setuptools* to take advantage of the convenience of **tests_require**, however, there may be drawbacks. *nose* warns that plugins may not be available when run through *setuptools*.

See [Integrating with setuptools / `python setup.py test` / `pytest-runner`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner)
and [*nosetests* *setuptools* command](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/commands.html#nosetests-setuptools-command).

### For example

Testing with setuptools integration:

setup.py

```
[...]
'version': '0.0.1',
'install_requires': [],
'tests_require': ['numpy'],
'cmdclass': {'test': PyTest},
'extras_require': {
    'testing': ['pytest'],
},
[...]
```

sh

```
(env) > python setup.py develop
(env) > easy_install pytest
(env) > python setup.py test -a "--pdb"
```

Or, testing without setuptools integration:

setup.py

```
[...]
'version': '0.0.1',
'install_requires': [],
'extras_require': {
    'testing': ['pytest', 'numpy'],
},
[...]
```

sh

```
(env) > pip install -e .[testing]
(env) > pytest.py --pdb
```

Comment: test_require is deprecated as of now