# pip install fails to install extras when not using quotes

Tags: python, pip, zsh

I wanted to try and understand why does this (for example) fail:

```
pip install python-jose[cryptography]
```

which is the way the docs tells you to install it - https://pypi.org/project/python-jose/

The error I get is:

> zsh: no matches found: python-jose[cryptography]

while this works:

```
pip install 'python-jose[cryptography]'
```

The same happens with other packages, and only by luck I stumbled across the docs for mypy-boto3 which showed the quotes as the way to install it: https://pypi.org/project/mypy-boto3/

I was about to try and create a pull request with a fix to the python-jose docs, but then I looked at the docs for installing packages and saw this:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

> Install a package with setuptools extras.

```
$ pip install SomePackage[PDF] 
$ pip install git+https://git.repo/some_pkg.git#egg=SomePackage[PDF] 
$ pip install .[PDF]  # project in current directory 
$ pip install SomePackage[PDF]==3.0 $ pip install SomePackage[PDF,EPUB]  # multiple extras
```

Nothing tells you to use quotes...except for mypy-boto3, god bless them.
Where does the problem lie? (surely with my machine...)

My env is:

Mac OS
Python 3.7.6
pip 20.1

Same thing happens with latest pipenv

Comment: Perhaps this is specific to zsh?  The command works without quotes in bash, for example.

Comment: Perhaps: The hyphen makes the difference and you need to enclose the relevant text together in a set of quotation marks. This is like specifying a path where you have empty spaces.

Comment: @snakecharmerb yeah that was it, turns out "zsh uses square brackets for globbing / pattern matching." which means you need to enclose it with quotes. from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539798/zsh-no-matches-found-requestssecurity. I couldn't find it until I looked for 'zsh' also

Comment: @snakecharmerb if you want to write something i'll mark it as an answer

Comment: Better to mark this as a dupe of the Q you linked to, if you agree?

Comment: @snakecharmerb right, thanks. flagged as dup.