# Decoding jwt token with PyJWT in python giving error Algorithm not supported

Tags: python, jwt, keycloak, pyjwt

I am using PyJWT to decode the JWT token coming from keycloak.

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6MWpiUExrTndMVTBkTHk3a0NIT1pyS2FJd3FPMXFrbThDeGtvVHg2QzFBIn0.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.aksSjBU5hJ1rtn43NtbMt8E6gaGmJXDrtGDI7j0T7eo6PAcnUxG4spYNNhyksXVr3ZFvua2WyTKnZirqaJUI3zzdLj-XkE7zYCYWoJpjXITmmlj5oszD3pcRdGeyUVyQV49tIiUfUFi1KoIt9K016mH2s_beFrN3TYSjuLh5Epdk_dpNBh9YE_1f3opwsEbN2Jgz_j-VB6cQHq17RzWQIVSd6ZvftAWDWdc6nobOvTy1mZAA_DgsXwdjuNc8Qv36ztuDzkT-raCnuLH479ciBOFQZ0946obIE4ddJKpr7lnVupcbQZ6lDM_QZHz1hwkYqgSU-Ui8NHaWlqt4HJ5-9A

my code

```
import jwt
import traceback


try:
    public_key = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhlOIQLHXwZoS3w9SBtvZ1ea4ftWmWnP+HCwlvs7XoJ9EhS+ZQEP7Z25tjW3I8mjUVL0XETrOOjQsD8O2nRBqizJsRaB8L9xsXdJmPHVTx7nphaBPtY5YHxxYqpwEC5rAKtx54YJxw6Ggeicmv+xXtaaDf/VALh5xxpa1U6yP5oqk3yV27yA0beQFVsdugkcfYN0C2FldaUcF9yTUf/KNHTYSu3Ar7iN9U+qEHwaznrLShwh7iknldTKTgEw3liHL8K/5ZlqxHPsL02InwZMaIRic3zNIgVvwedroM6nqZBB4mi1+T0dZn4qsNkG4D0w7IE7MTRgyyYARqrGEq5yOFwIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

    secret_key = "base-flask-oidc-secret-key"
    token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6MWpiUExrTndMVTBkTHk3a0NIT1pyS2FJd3FPMXFrbThDeGtvVHg2QzFBIn0.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.aksSjBU5hJ1rtn43NtbMt8E6gaGmJXDrtGDI7j0T7eo6PAcnUxG4spYNNhyksXVr3ZFvua2WyTKnZirqaJUI3zzdLj-XkE7zYCYWoJpjXITmmlj5oszD3pcRdGeyUVyQV49tIiUfUFi1KoIt9K016mH2s_beFrN3TYSjuLh5Epdk_dpNBh9YE_1f3opwsEbN2Jgz_j-VB6cQHq17RzWQIVSd6ZvftAWDWdc6nobOvTy1mZAA_DgsXwdjuNc8Qv36ztuDzkT-raCnuLH479ciBOFQZ0946obIE4ddJKpr7lnVupcbQZ6lDM_QZHz1hwkYqgSU-Ui8NHaWlqt4HJ5-9A"
    # token_json = jwt.decode(token, secret_key, algorithms=['HS256', 'RS256'], audience='account')
    token_json = jwt.decode(token, public_key, algorithms=['HS256', 'RS256'], audience='account')
    print(access_token_json)
    
except Exception:
    print(traceback.print_exc())
```

according to jwt.io, it is showing header

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "z1jbPLkNwLU0dLy7kCHOZrKaIwqO1qkm8CxkoTx6C1A"
}
```

i tried with public key as well as secret key, both are giving me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 232, in _verify_signature
    alg_obj = self._algorithms[alg]
KeyError: 'RS256'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jwt_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    access_token_json = jwt.decode(access_token, public_key, algorithms=['HS256', 'RS256'], audience='account')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 119, in decode
    decoded = self.decode_complete(jwt, key, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 95, in decode_complete
    **kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 149, in decode_complete
    self._verify_signature(signing_input, header, signature, key, algorithms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 239, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidAlgorithmError("Algorithm not supported")
jwt.exceptions.InvalidAlgorithmError: Algorithm not supported
```

if i am removing 'RS256' from algorithms list.

```
token_json = jwt.decode(token, public_key, algorithms=['HS256'], audience='account')
```

then i am getting error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jwt_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    token_json = jwt.decode(token, public_key, algorithms=['HS256'], audience='account')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 119, in decode
    decoded = self.decode_complete(jwt, key, algorithms, options, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 95, in decode_complete
    **kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 149, in decode_complete
    self._verify_signature(signing_input, header, signature, key, algorithms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 229, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidAlgorithmError("The specified alg value is not allowed")
```

How do i solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

################### answer #######################

I was able to solve it by

Installing cryptography as suggested by @KlausD in the comment

```
pip install cryptography
```

and also changed public key to

```
public_key = """-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAhlOIQLHXwZoS3w9SBtvZ1ea4ftWmWnP+HCwlvs7XoJ9EhS+ZQEP7Z25tjW3I8mjUVL0XETrOOjQsD8O2nRBqizJsRaB8L9xsXdJmPHVTx7nphaBPtY5YHxxYqpwEC5rAKtx54YJxw6Ggeicmv+xXtaaDf/VALh5xxpa1U6yP5oqk3yV27yA0beQFVsdugkcfYN0C2FldaUcF9yTUf/KNHTYSu3Ar7iN9U+qEHwaznrLShwh7iknldTKTgEw3liHL8K/5ZlqxHPsL02InwZMaIRic3zNIgVvwedroM6nqZBB4mi1+T0dZn4qsNkG4D0w7IE7MTRgyyYARqrGEq5yOFwIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""
```

Comment: Old version of `PyJWT`? `cryptography` not installed?

Comment: @KlausD. i am using latest on.

Comment: Is that an answer to the first or second question?

Comment: @KlausD. sorry, i don't have cryptography installed. what is the module name to install it?

Comment: `cryptography`?

Comment: @KlausD. that was the missing piece. Thank you

Answer (score 28):

After reading the [PyJWT installation guide again](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#cryptographic-dependencies-optional), it seems that for certain signature algorithms like **RSA**, the [python cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) library needs to be installed.

I resolved the problem by installing the dependecy:

```sh
pip install pyjwt[crypto]
```

Comment: Or `pip install "pyjwt[crypto]"` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30539963/950462). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue **(Python version 3.6.7 on Mac)** but the solution was totally different that I resolved with the help of provided answers in addition to some other steps as well.

> **Note:** Don't think, if you have activated virtual environment and keeping it active for a long time, it will work with same efficiency as per our expectations. So make sure to reactivate it even you keep your PC, Laptop, System etc. in sleep mode.
>
> See below what actually I faced and finally got it resolved.

##### How I had generated the Private & Public keys?

Below are the 2 commands to execute to get private & public keys.

```
> openssl genrsa -out jwt-key 4096
> openssl rsa -in jwt-key -pubout > jwt-key.pub
```

##### Get JWT (Encode)

`encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({ "user_id": 1 }, private_key, algorithm='RS256')`

It was successful in the project with different virtual environment. Now I tried to decode this JWT in another project with different virtual environment (which had been activated few days back and was still active).

```
payload = jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, public_key, algorithms=['RS256'])
```

And saw this error/exception message.

```
3.6/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 226, in _verify_signature
raise InvalidAlgorithmError('Algorithm not supported')
jwt.exceptions.InvalidAlgorithmError: Algorithm not supported
```

Oops! Let's try to solve it!

#### How did I resolve?

After reading the answers I followed the steps and installed `pyjwt[crypto]` ,  `cryptography` (anyone of this) packages inside my already activated virtual environment but then also my problems did not get resolve. It was making me think about trying another algorithm but I thought to try and brainstorm for other solutions.

I just took a look inside `<virtualenv_dir>/lib/site-packages/` and found there was no `cryptography` package installed rather it was installed outside in the actual Python environment.

So now, I had some idea to resolve and performed the below  steps to resolve the issue.

1. Deactivated the virtual environment
2. Ran `pip uninstall pyjwt[crypto]`
3. Ran `pip uninstall cryptography`
4. Activated the virtual environment
5. Ran `pip install pyjwt[crypto]`
6. Ran `pip install cryptography`

Now, when I decoded the encoded JWT, it worked well.

##### Decode JWT

```
> payload = jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, public_key, algorithms=['RS256'])`
> payload
{ "user_id": 1 }
```

Finally, the bug is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Why the error occurs is explained [Here](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/docs/usage.rst#audience-claim-aud).
You can solve the issue just avoid checking the audience data of the jwt:

```
import jwt
ALGORITHM = "HS256"

options={
        'verify_exp': False,  # Skipping expiration date check
        'verify_aud': False 
        }

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, YOUR_SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM], options=options)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, detail=str(e))
```