# Authenticate a GET request to Google Play Purchase API with service account python

Tags: python, android, in-app-purchase, google-api-python-client, google-play-developer-api

I need to verify purchases of my android App from my AWS lambda in python.

I have seen many posts of how to do so and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get) and here is the code I have written :

```
url = f"{google_verify_purchase_endpoint}/{product_id}/tokens/{token}"
response = requests.get(url=url)
data = response.json()
logging.info(f"Response from Google Play API : {data}")
```

When I do so, it throws a 401 status code not allowed.
Alright, I have created a service account to allow the request with OAuth, but how can I use it to allow the request ?

Unfortunately I can't use the `google-api-python-client` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858290/11665178) which is too big for my AWS lambda maximum size of 250Mb unzipped package.

So my question is to use the service account with a simple GET requests or how can I authenticate automatically without the `google-api-python-client` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pre-Requisites and Assumptions

It looks like you have already set-up a service account but need a hand with obtaining a JSON Web Token (JWT) before going after the verify_purchase endpoint. Generating a JWT is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests). You should read this to understand what the following code is doing.

I note that you have a storage-constraint, but you are almost-definitely going to need an additional library to deal with the cryptographic aspect of the token generation. PyJwt is reasonably small (including its requirements).

Let's install this first:

```
pip3 install PyJwt
```

### Obtaining a Private Key

Next, let's grab our Service Account Private Key from Google Cloud.

```
Open your project in Google Cloud.

Go to "APIs & Services".

Go to "Credentials".

Click "Service Account".

Find your Service Account and Select "Manage Keys".

Select "Create new key" from the "ADD KEY" drop down.

Select JSON.

Save this JSON file to a secure location accessible by your script.
```

### Putting it to Use

Now we can make a start on a Python Script. Here is an *example* to get you started (you should review this before putting it into production):

```py
import time
import json
import requests
import jwt

claim_start = int(time.time())

# Generate a claim header, this will always be the same.
header = {"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}

# This is a claim for 1hr access to the android publisher API.
# Replace <<EMAIL ADDRESS OF YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT>> as appropriate.
claims = {
  "iss": "<<EMAIL ADDRESS OF YOUR SERVICE ACCOUNT>>",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher",
  "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "exp": claim_start + 3600,
  "iat": claim_start
}

with open("<<PATH TO JSON FILE>>", 'r') as f:
    json_key = json.load(f)
    key = json_key.get('private_key')

# Generate a signed jwt
token = jwt.encode(claims, key, headers=header, algorithm="RS256")

# Mandatory parameters required by GCloud.
params = {
  "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
  "assertion": token
}

r = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token", data=params)
r.raise_for_status()
access_token = r.json()['access_token']
```

### Using our Access Token

The `access_token` can then be used as a JWT bearer for your project. Please note, I have changed the `token` variable to `subscription_token` from your original post to make it clear that it has nothing to do with this authentication mechanism. (It refers to "the token provided to the user's device when the subscription was purchased." as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get) that you provided.)

```py
headers = {
  "Host": "www.googleapis.com",
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

google_verify_purchase_endpoint=""
product_id=""
subscription_token=""

url = f"{google_verify_purchase_endpoint}/{product_id}/tokens/{subscription_token}"
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
logging.info(f"Response from Google Play API : {data}")
```

### Closing Remarks

This is merely meant to serve as an introduction into authenticating against the Google Cloud APIs without the SDK. Ultimately, you are responsible for the security of your project and anyone else reading this should probably use the SDK where possible. I also suggest that you neaten the above code up into subsequent functions to call upon where appropriate.

Good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, be sure i will test soon. I need to make some changes for my in app products and i will be testing it ! 
I have already tested PyJWT in my lambda and it's working fine, i have no arch issues or anything so it's a good point.

Comment: Sounds good, let me know if you run into any issues with this.

Comment: I have managed to test it ! I have got the following error : `Algorithm 'RS256' could not be found. Do you have cryptography installed?` but i have installed `PyJwt==2.6.0` in my Lambda

Comment: I have run the flow on my local python machine with the correct tokens etc.. and it's working fine thank you very much ! I just need to solve my crypto issue from the AWS lambda, it would be very nice of you if you could help me out but i am already granting you the bounty because it's exactly what i wanted

Comment: i needed to install `pyjwt[crypto]` :)

Comment: Awesome, cheers mate!

When I installed PyJwt on my machine it pulled the crypto functions automatically. Looks like that isn't always the case, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602828/decoding-jwt-token-with-pyjwt-in-python-giving-error-algorithm-not-supported).

`pip3 install pyjwt[crypto]`

You need to install the cryptography library in your lamda instance.

Comment: Ah ha, you got there first, nice one!

Answer (score 0):

After following the tutorial for Authorization here: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

We will have the `access_token`, which we need to send in Authorization header like this:

```
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: At the first step of the tutorial i am blocked because : `You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.`

Comment: Does this help @Tom3652? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68764885/google-oauth-2-0-api-authentication-error-error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-do

Comment: The below answer of @Tom is working very fine and is exactly what i wanted.