# zsh: no matches found: uvicorn[standard]

Tags: fastapi

I am following the example to install unvicorn:

```
https://www.uvicorn.org/
```

by doing:

```
pip install uvicorn[standard]
```

But received the following error:

```
 % pip install uvicorn[standard]
zsh: no matches found: uvicorn[standard]
```

However this works:

```
 % pip install uvicorn
```

I am on MacPro with Python 3.7.

Comment: Seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30539798/1707353)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zsh: no matches found: requests\[security\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539798/zsh-no-matches-found-requestssecurity)

Answer (score 28):

You need to use single quotes.

```
pip install 'uvicorn[standard]'
```

Answer (score 11):

zsh uses [square brackets for globbing / pattern matching](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html#l137).

So, if you need to pass literal square brackets as an argument to a command, you either need to escape them or quote the argument like this:

```
pip install 'uvicorn[standard]'
```

If you want to disable [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) for the `pip` command permanently, you can do so by adding this to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias pip='noglob pip'
```

Comment: this is how an answer should look like! thanks!

Comment: did the same for poetry

Answer (score 0):

For zsh you can configure it to just run the command without trying to do any glob expansion when there are no files to match:

```
unsetopt nomatch
```

Comment: unsetopt: command not found