# Error installing cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000] in Python 3.7

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-sql, pg8000

I am trying to connect to a Cloud SQL postgresql instance through python 3.7 from my local machine. I am following the guide from the README [cloud-sql-python-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector). There it says to pip install the necessary module with the following command, for a postgresql instance:

```
pip install cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000]
```

But when I run this in my terminal, I get the following error:

```
zsh: no matches found: cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000]
```

There does exist the package `cloud-sql-python-connector` without the `[pg8000]` part associated to it, but then I can't run the next part establishing a connection, because `pg8000` is not defined:

```
def getconn() -> pg8000.connections.Connection:
    conn: pg8000.connections.Connection = connector.connect(
        "project:region:instance",
        "pg8000",
        user="postgres",
        password="XXXXXXXX",
        db="your-db-name"
    )
    return conn
```

Any advice on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated!

Comment: just a quick check, can you try running `python` to see what version that launches? I have the feeling you *might* have python2 installed. I tried copying/pasting the pip install command and for me that worked

Comment: @EdoAkse sure, this was the output: Python 3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08)

Comment: @EdoAkse I just realised that square brackets are interpreted as a pattern on the command line - I needed to just escape the brackets and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is actually a long-running issue with the **zsh** terminal for mac users. It doesn't like pip installs with the square brackets. See [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539798/zsh-no-matches-found-requestssecurity)

As mentioned escaping the square brackets works and so should the following:

```
pip install 'cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000]'
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end all I needed to do was escape the square brackets in the pip install command. This is because square brackets are interpreted as a pattern on the command line ([article](https://grepleigh.medium.com/zsh-no-matches-found-ea5bdc551ff1)). So the final command that worked was:

```
pip install cloud-sql-python-connector\[pg8000\]
```

I'm still new to the terminal, but hopefully this helps anyone else having such problems.