# Using poetry to install openai[embeddings]

Tags: python, openai-api, python-poetry

I want to use the following import in my python code:

```
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
```

but it's not installed.
poetry shows:

```
annotated-types    0.6.0        Reusable constraint types to use with...
anyio              4.2.0        High level compatibility layer for mu...
authlib            1.3.0        The ultimate Python library in buildi...
certifi            2023.11.17   Python package for providing Mozilla'...
cffi               1.16.0       Foreign Function Interface for Python...
charset-normalizer 3.3.2        The Real First Universal Charset Dete...
cryptography       41.0.7       cryptography is a package which provi...
distro             1.9.0        Distro - an OS platform information API
dnspython          2.4.2        DNS toolkit
exceptiongroup     1.2.0        Backport of PEP 654 (exception groups)
h11                0.14.0       A pure-Python, bring-your-own-I/O imp...
httpcore           1.0.2        A minimal low-level HTTP client.
httpx              0.26.0       The next generation HTTP client.
idna               3.6          Internationalized Domain Names in App...
numpy              1.26.3       Fundamental package for array computi...
openai             1.7.0        The official Python library for the o...
pandas             2.1.4        Powerful data structures for data ana...
pycparser          2.21         C parser in Python
pydantic           2.5.3        Data validation using Python type hints
pydantic-core      2.14.6       
pymongo            4.6.1        Python driver for MongoDB <http://www...
python-dateutil    2.8.2        Extensions to the standard Python dat...
pytz               2023.3.post1 World timezone definitions, modern an...
requests           2.31.0       Python HTTP for Humans.
six                1.16.0       Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
sniffio            1.3.0        Sniff out which async library your co...
tqdm               4.66.1       Fast, Extensible Progress Meter
typing-extensions  4.9.0        Backported and Experimental Type Hint...
tzdata             2023.4       Provider of IANA time zone data
urllib3            2.1.0        HTTP library with thread-safe connect...
validators         0.22.0       Python Data Validation for Humans™
weaviate-client    3.26.0       A python native Weaviate client
```

poetry add openai[embeddings] fails as an improper zsh syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [zsh: no matches found: requests\[security\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539798/zsh-no-matches-found-requestssecurity), for zsh you need to quote the package name.